# PowerShell script to find the process and kill the process

Tags: powershell

I am a beginner in PowerShell script and trying to make a small PowerShell script to find the PID by searching the filename and if shows that multiple PIDs then take the TOP one and kill that PID.

I am able to find the PID through [Get-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Process), but how do I store the value of the top one in variable and then kill that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One of the nice things about PowerShell, is you usually don't need to store values. You can just pipe commands together.

Something like this should work:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "myprocess" } | Select-Object -First 1 | Stop-Process
```

And the breakdown is:

1. [Get-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Process) gets a list of all of the running processes
2. [Where-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/Where-Object) filters the list of processes to only those whose "Name" is equal to "myprocess"
3. [Select-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object) the `-First 1` selects the first entry from the list
4. [Stop-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Stop-Process) stops the process passed to it

Answer (score 2):

Add a string argument to [Get-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Process) and you are shorter:

```
Get-Process vlc | Stop-Process
```

Comment: I suppose this would work if your program runs in a single process. If you want to kill a specific process in, say, Firefox, you'll have to pipe your instructions the way heavyd suggeted, otherwise you'll only kill the parent process (and all children), not the one you want to kill specifically.

Comment: Firefox is huge, I just stick to the question above.

Comment: Agreed. If it works for you this way, no need to change anything.

Comment: @Scott: as I said, if the process you want to kill is a single-process program or service, then you don't need to pipe multiple instructions. If, on the other hand, the program or service you want to kill runs in multi-process mode, like Firefox, or Chrome, first you must determine which of those processes you want to kill, based on parameters you'll determine (CPU usage, order in the process chain, RAM usage, you name it), then pipe the right instructions as to its order in the process list. In the case of a runaway browser process, the problem is what to kill without crashing the program.

Comment: Oh, got it! I meant to say that, in my example with Firefox, there's a parent process (firefox.exe with the lowest PID), and child processes with higher PIDs. If you kill the lower-PIDed firefox.exe process, you terminate the whole process tree, whereas if you target one of the child processes, you might end up crashing or freezing the program, but you won't actively terminate it: it'll terminate itself because you killed an essential part of its runtime code. That's what I meant.

Comment: Only one way to find out... I powered (guffaw, guffaw) my PS console, typed André's commands and got error messages. Gonna try your way in a moment.

Comment: Tried both ways, as admin, with a process and a service, didn't work.

Comment: @Didier So, are you retracting your first comment, and saying that Andre’s answer doesn’t work at all?

Comment: I don't have to retract or confirm or affirm or whatever: I said that IF André's goal was to stop a single-process program or service, then why bother adding which process in the process tree was to be stopped, since there was only ONE. This said, the other method that was suggested, namely 'Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "myprocess" } | Select-Object -First 1 | Stop-Process' doesn't work either, so do you want to spend the rest of the day bickering over who shot his cherry pit the farthest, or are you *really* going to pitch in...?

Comment: Don't mean to boast, but my method works. It does...

Comment: @Scott: Get-Process -Id 1664 | Stop-Process does work for subprocesses.

Comment: *Why* does it work? Due to positional parameters?